# Joomla 3.2, get works, post doesn't

Tags: joomla, mootools, joomla3.0

So I have this JS code:

```
myClass = new Class({
  initialize: function() {
    this.btnSubmit = document.id('btnSubmit');
    this.sendData = new Request({
      "url":"/",
      "method":"post",
      "data": {"option":"com_my4quiz", "controller":"conduit", "task":"save", "hrdata":"foo"},
      "onSuccess": this.handleResult.bind(this)
    });

    this.btnSubmitObserver = function() { this.sendData.send(); }.bind(this);
    this.btnSubmit.addEvent("click", this.btnSubmitObserver);
  },

  handleResult: function(stuff) {
    //do stuff
  }
});
```

If I'm posting this to my Joomla 3.2.0 component it returns the home page.  As soon as I switch to get, it sends the data to the correct place and I get what I expect.

Comment: Parkinson's IT law: you can see that an IT-project is dying, when they start to grow the version number exponentially. :-)

Comment: Danke for that!  I'm sure that tidbit will come in handy.

Comment: Can you post the controller code, it's what will be affecting the result.

Answer (score 1):

I think its due to your controller page loads the entire view.

This may happen due to inside your controller `save()`. function not rendering any specific view .

So the solution is after the Ajax result just render the proper layout or just put an `exit();`

At the end of your `save()`

```
exit();
```

or

```
$view->setLayout($layoutName);
$view->display();
```

Hope its helps..

Comment: I never reach the "conduit" controller if I post, only if I get.

Comment: try this url index.php?option=com_my4quiz&task=conduit.save and only pass data as you additional params